# Is it possible to build tianocore UEFI for intel x64?

Tags: uefi, bios

I have an AsRock z97e-itx with 4th gen i3 onboard and I'm wondering if it is possible to build tianocore UEFI for it. I've heard it might be a problem if it has Intel Boot Guard.

Answer (score 0):

By itself, [Tianocore](http://www.tianocore.org/) doesn't provide everything needed as firmware for a computer. *In theory,* though, you can combine Tianocore with [CoreBoot,](https://www.coreboot.org) which provides the missing bits. There are two very big caveats, though:

- **Is your system supported?** -- CoreBoot provides support for a number of motherboards and chipsets, but I don't see your specific board listed on the [CoreBoot support page.](https://www.coreboot.org/Supported_Motherboards) It's still conceivable it would work with a configuration for a similar motherboard, but I certainly can't promise that.
- **How much effort and money are you willing to invest?** -- Building CoreBoot, building Tianocore, and merging the two into a working binary represents a significant investment in time. This might include bricking your motherboard and time spent recovering from that. You might also need to buy an EEPROM programmer, learn to solder and de-solder components, etc. The last I checked, instructions for merging CoreBoot and Tianocore were rather vague. Some people claim to have succeeded in doing this, but if you want to try, you'll be playing on the very sharp point of the "bleeding edge."

You haven't said why you want to use Tianocore on your motherboard. For most users, it's not worth the effort. Personally, I've never done this, although I've been tempted to try, just for the learning experience.

Comment: Thanks for answering, @Rod Smith. My system is not supported by CoreBoot. And I thought Tianocore has its own built-in bootloader and wouldn't have to deal with CoreBoot since it's lack of support. I believe I need some kind of bootloader which can initialize hardware by using Intel FSP.

Comment: Tianocore is not a boot loader; it's (part of) a firmware. Boot loaders run atop firmware; they're things like GRUB, LILO, and ELILO. CoreBoot provides hardware initialization functions needed by Tianocore (or other CoreBoot payloads) to make a complete firmware image.

Comment: Thanks, mate. Ofcourse I know what GRUB is.))) According to Intel : Bootloader – another name for an “FSP Consumer”, as distinct from MBR-based loader for PC/AT BIOS. CoreBoot is an "FSP Consumer" this way. And again, according to Intel, you can use tianocore instead.